# React - componentWillReceiveProps does not execute when component rendered in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

New to React, so apologize in advance if this is an ignorant question. I'm using componentWillReceiveProps to execute a function post-render. The function is passed in as a prop. Trying to write a unit test to show that the passed in function gets called, but componentWillReceiveProps does not seem to get called when I render the component in my test. It works when I run the app in the browser, but not in the test.

Here's the test:

```
it('should call function \'selectAll\' when isDefaultSelectAll is true and component is rendered.', ()=> {
    const selectAllMock = jest.genMockFunction();
    const isDefaultSelectAll = true;
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent {isDefaultSelectAll, selectAllMock} />);;
    expect(selectAllMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Here's the code being tested:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log('GOT HERE');
   if (nextProps.isDefaultSelectAll === true) {
       nextProps.selectAll();
   }
}
```

Even the log statement does not seem to be hit, and I'm not sure why. Googling has not yielded an answer.

Edit for the first answer - attempted to do a second render as follows, but still not having any luck:

```
const isDefaultSelectAll = false; 
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent {isDefaultSelectAll, selectAllMock} />); 
isDefaultSelectAll = true; 
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent {isDefaultSelectAll, selectAllMock} />);
```

Comment: A second render means to force  the same component render again. So you have to change the props after rendering the component. Not sure how to do it with the react test utils, but with enzyme it would work like [this](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html).

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is not called on the initial render, as stated in the docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Either try to use another lifecycle method or re-render the component in your test.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, tried this, but to no avail, still not getting hit. Sorry for the code soup, not sure how to format it in a nicer way, but basically just a second call to TestUtils.renderIntoDocument in the test.

`const isDefaultSelectAll = false;
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent {isDefaultSelectAll, selectAllMock} />);
isDefaultSelectAll = true;
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent {isDefaultSelectAll, selectAllMock} />);`